# Fading chords in d3js chord graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chord-diagram

I'm a total beginner with d3js, so please be patient if my question looks dumb.

I'm trying to reproduce a chord graph like the [one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006) proposed by Mike Bostock. In the code by Bostock if you go with your mouse on an arc, all the chords that are not involved (as *target* as well as *source*) in the arc will fade.

I'd like to change it in order to let all the chords fade except the one on which there is a mouse (in order to emphasize one single two-way relationship).

I've added a `fade_single` function that is triggered when the mouse is over a chord:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "chord")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(chord.chords)
    .enter().append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.target.index); })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(r0))
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .on("mouseover", fade_single(0.1))
    .on("mouseout", fade_single(1));
```

The `fade_single` function follows:

```
function fade_single(opacity) {
  return function(g, i) {
    svg.selectAll("g.chord path")
        .filter(function(d) {
          //return d.source.index != 0 && d.target.index != 0;
        })
      .transition()
        .style("opacity", opacity);
  };
}
```

The problem is that I don't know what to put in the commented line, i.e. to filter out all the relationship that are have not the row and column of the single chord. I've tried to play with the *subindexes* but the parameter `i` only gives you the row, so I don't know how to isolate the chord I want to exclude from the fading.

Any idea? Any hint?

Thank you,

Elisa

Comment: What exactly do you want to fade on mouseover? All the chords except for the ones that start at the highlighted one?

Comment: Thanks Lars. All the chords except for the ones that start (or finish) at the highlighted one.

Comment: So that would be the same as the example, no?

Comment: No. I want to highlight a single chord (aka one single "flow"), not a group of chords touching the same arc.

Comment: And how do you know which one to highlight?

Comment: I want to highlight the one with the mouse over.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38286/discussion-between-mellin-and-lars-kotthoff)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fade everything but the current elemeent, the easiest way is to use the `this` reference to the current DOM element:

```
function fade_single(opacity) {
  return function() {
    var me = this;
    svg.selectAll("g.chord path")
        .filter(function(d) {
          return this != me;
        })
      .transition()
        .style("opacity", opacity);
  };
}
```